# Rails, dashboard namespace and cancancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have an app for managing restaurants where each restaurant has a dashboard(a mini control panel to change some settings if you are allowed to). I noticed that even though I have defined some abilities, any user can access any restaurant's dashboard. Basicly, I would like users to have access only if they have a position at the restaurant. Currently, the ability.rb looks like this

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      user.roles.each do |role|
        role.permissions.each do |permission|
          can permission.action.to_sym, permission.subject_class.constantize, restaurant_id: role.restaurant_id
          can permission.action.to_sym, permission.subject_class.constantize, id: role.restaurant_id if permission.subject_class == "Restaurant"
        end
      end
      can :read, Restaurant
      can :read, Product
      can :read, Category
    end
  end
end
```

The controllers folder has a folder 'dashboard' where the restricted controllers are and the routes look like this

```
  namespace :dashboard do
    resources :restaurants, except: [:index, :destroy] do
      resources :products
      resources :categories
      resources :roles
      resources :positions
      resources :tables
      resources :reservations
    end
  end
```

I searched in the cancan documentation for this but I could not find anything that could help me. Thank you for any suggestions on how to fix that!

Comment: you need a scope on can :manage, :all, i.e. can :manage, :all, restaurant_id: user.restaurant_id otherwise this would be the expected behavior. FWIW I'm not sure if you can add a scope to the :all method

Comment: The :manage, :all is for the admin. I only want to disallow a normal user to enter a restaurants dashboard.